# How to avoide parsing HTML every time when program executed?

Tags: java, r, parsing

I am writing a program where I am parsing a large amount of HTML data and creating objects using it. Every time I run the program it has to parse through the data again and then create the objects which are very time-consuming.

**Is there something I can do so that when I add code, the program can pick up where it left off with all the objects having been created?**

If this description of what I am trying to do isn't good enough, R does this.

I know the language is very different (it isn't a compiling language), but when a variable is created, it stays in the environment. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can serialize parsed object and de-serialized whenever you want previously parsed object.

Comment: What does serializing mean? Sorry, I'm a little new.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RStudio, you can save the environment on your machine and when re-opening the project you import the environment again.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to find a feature like this in Java.